# Gauss circle problem : a simple asymptotic estimation.

Tags: geometry, asymptotics, integer-lattices, arithmetic-geometry

> Find the number of integer points lying in or inside a circle of radius $n\in \mathbb N$ centered at the origin.

The problem asks for all $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z^2$ such that $a^2+b^2\leq n^2$. Looking at such points lying strictly in the North-East quadrant, pick an $a\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $b$ run through $\{1,\ldots,\lfloor \sqrt{n^2-a^2}\rfloor\}$ : there are exactly $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor \sqrt{n^2-k^2} \rfloor$ integer points strictly in the quadrant.

Multiply that by $4$ to account for all $4$ quadrants, add the origin and points on the $x$ and $y$ axis and the total number is $$1+4\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \sqrt{n^2-k^2} \rfloor$$

I'm interested in asymptotics of this sum. A trivial estimate is the following:$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \sqrt{n^2-k^2} \rfloor &= \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{n^2-k^2} + O(n)\\ &= n^2\cdot \left(\frac 1n \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}\right) + O(n) \\ &=n^2 \left( \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt + o(1)\right) + O(n) \\ &= \frac \pi 4n^2 + o(n^2)\end{align} $$

Hence $$1+4\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \sqrt{n^2-k^2} \rfloor = \pi n^2 + o(n^2)$$

> Is there a way to refine the estimate above and get $\pi n^2 + O(n)$ instead (or something better) ?

Comment: $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ forms [OEIS A000328](http://oeis.org/A000328), which has further links. The [Gauss's Circle Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html) page at Wolfram Mathworld shows that in fact, $N(r) = \pi r^2 + E(r)$, with $\left\lvert E(r) \right\rvert \le 2 \sqrt{2} \pi r$, which means your solution is already $O(n)$ (actually $O(n^{131/208})$ per Huxley, 2003). Therefore, the aswer to the stated question is **You already have** $O(n)$ or better.

Comment: If I understand well you have for $0<\delta<R$ the **Lema 2.5** (page 19), or also **Lema 2.6** (in page 21). This is a text in spanish of high quality that I found in internet from [Universidad Autónoma de Madrid](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/fchamizo/posgrado/DEASusanadelaRubia.pdf).

Comment: @NominalAnimal I need (preferably elementary) proofs, not statements...

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: Why did you then ask something other than what you need? If you need proof, say so! If you had bothered to check the links I mentioned, they show the reasoning quite clearly; the exact proof for the lowest bound ($O(n^{131/208})$) is in the Huxley 2003 article; Gauss himself proved the $O(n)$ bound. You know, the guy the problem is named after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate $\displaystyle \frac 1n \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt + o(1)$ can easily be refined .

Indeed, $$\begin{align}0\leq \frac 1n \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}} - \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}} - \sqrt{1-t^2}\right)dt\\ &\leq\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{(k+1)^2}{n^2}}\right)dt  \\ &= \frac 1n \end{align}$$

Hence $\displaystyle \frac 1n \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt + O(\frac 1n)$ and $$1+4\sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \sqrt{n^2-k^2} \rfloor = \pi n^2 + O(n)$$

Answer (score 5):

Pick a square with unit side length centered at every lattice point inside the region $x^2+y^2=n^2$, i.e. the circle with radius $n$ centered at the origin. Those squares entirely cover the circle with radius $n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, but any square lies inside a circle with radius $n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, hence the number of lattice points is between $\pi\left( n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$ and $\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$, so it is $\pi n^2+O(n)$.

For info about the Voronoi bound, please see [this survey](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/cprob.pdf).

Comment: Very nice summary! And, $\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - \pi\left(n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = 2\sqrt{2}\pi n$, the limit mentioned in my comment to the question.