# Lattice points in a circle

Tags: analysis, number-theory

I've started reading about Gauss circle problem.
As I've read H.steinhaus(one of the great polish mathematicians of the history) has proved : for every positive integer "n" there exists a circle of area "n" which contains exactly "n" lattice points (point with integer coordinates).
I'm looking for his proof and some other articles about main problem(function which counts lattice point in a circle).

Comment: If you manage to find "Recreational Mathematics" by Paul Yiu (2003 edition), it has a section dedicated to the subject of lattice points inside and on a circle. Particularly, you will find that for large $R$, the number $K(R)$ of lattice points inside and on the circle of radius $\sqrt{R}$ satisfies $$\pi R- \pi \left(2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{R}-2\right)<K(R)<\pi R + \pi \left(2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{R}+2\right)$$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1889393/44121

Comment: @rtybase Actually the main problem is about the error function of K(R). This inquality will show that Er(R)=O(R). But this was improved by Hardy to O(R^0.5). But Tnx anyway!!