# Gauss circle problem

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that the number $\mu(n)$ of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ with $x^{2}+y^{2}<n$ satisfies $\mu(n)/n \rightarrow \pi $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

If we consider the lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}<1,0>+\mathbb{Z}<0,1>$ and $X=\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^{2}|x^{2}+y^{2}<n \rbrace$ from Minkowski's theorm we know that $X\cap L \neq \emptyset $ i want to know that is there any formula for $\mu(n)$?
beacuse if we know the formula we can comput the limit.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889361/gauss-circle-problem-a-simple-asymptotic-estimation).